# Singular and plural language in Deut. 4:25

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, vaeschanan, rebuke-tochacha

Why does the Pasuk ([Deut. 4:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0504.htm#25)) switch between singular and plural when building up to the consequences of what "you will [do]"?

"When you (sing.) will have children and grandchildren, and you (pl.) will have been in the land (a long time)..."

Comment: I didn't check, but it seems as if all of the verbs are plural after the word תוליד — maybe one person giving birth to all of them? All of the bad ones are descended from one person?

Comment: Perhaps now they are כאיש אחד בלב אחד but once they settle and spread out in the land they will become a "_plural_".

Comment: The obvious answer is like @ba  .  Sortof.  The You in plural refers to the many generations of people who have been living in the land.   This is true in both English and Hebrew, I'm frankly a bit confused by the question unless there is some drash in mind.  There is no expectation that the individual who sired the children and grandchildren is the subject of the second half of the statement, rather the subject has switched to said children.

Comment: @Avi, then it should switch to "they", not "you (pl.)", no?

Comment: @SethJ and Separate the current generation from the Nation? Gd Forbid!   But now I understand your question thanks.